# Get Data at the interval of 10 minutes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which has the below structure.

```
+ ----------------------+--------------+--------+---------+
| timeStamp             | value        | type   |  id     |
+ ----------------------+--------------+--------+---------|
| '2010-01-14 00:00:00' | '11787.3743' | 'mean' |  1      |
| '2018-04-03 00:07:21' | '9.9908'     | 'std'  |  1      |
| '2018-04-03 00:10:00' | '11787.3743' | 'min'  |  1      |
+ ----------------------+--------------+--------+---------+
```

Now i want to write a select query where i can fetch the data on the basis of type.

Here you can see i want the data at the interval of 10 minutes only and the column 'mean_type'/'min_type'/'std_type' should be dynamic and should be made using the concat query like concat(id,'_','mean')

```
+ ----------------------+--------------+-------------+----------+
| timeStamp             | 1_mean       | 1_min       | 1_std    |
+ ----------------------+--------------+-------------+----------+
| '2010-01-14 00:00:00' | '11787.3743' |             |          |
| '2018-04-03 00:10:00' |              | '11787.3743 |          |
+ ----------------------+--------------+-------------+----------+
```

I have used the below query but it is not working :-

**Query :-**

```
select 
    to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from  m.timeStamp) / 600 )) * 600) 
    AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' as t,
    case type when 'mean' then value end as concat(id,'mean'),
    case type when 'min' then value end as concat(id,'min'),
    case type when 'std' then value end as concat(id,'std'),
    from measure m 
    where id=1
    GROUP by t
    order by t;
```

I am using postgres DB.

Comment: What exactly do you want the final result set to look like? And what do you mean by ' i want the data at the interval of 10 minutes only'?

Comment: It isn't clear to me why you must name the columns using the id value. Why not just include the id as a column?

Nevertheless, if you really need to dynamically name columns, you will need to use some variant of an EXECUTE statement. See this [link][1].


  [1]: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: What results are you looking for?

Comment: You cannot dynamically set the name of a column, using a normal select statement.